# Magento how to duplicate my own module

Tags: magento

My module is customize from this tutorial http://today24h.com/magento/magento-create-custom-payment-method.html.

my module is about add more bank transfer payment method. right now the module is working good. I want to add 5 more bank transfer payment tab. here's screenshot that I want

http://sevyshop.com/temp/1.png

I try to copy all files from app folder and rename all things. but it doesn't show the new tab. How can I do ? Please guild me.

I upload my module here:

> sevyshop.com/temp/payment.rar

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip : Check if you have well-formed your xml files for your modules in app/etc/modules folder.

Comment: yes I have copy and rename all things ex: Companyname2/Mymodule2. also in app/etc/modules.

Comment: the new module show on System>Config>Advance but the tab is doesn't show on payment method page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified if the new modules are installed in Magento (it should be listed in the adminpanel/ System > Configuration > Advanced)? And if there is any error in the Magento logs (var/log)?

Double check everything! For example the config.xml file of the module itself or system.xml file which creates the tab in admin panel, make sure you are renaming everything, all names and also directories correctly.

Comment: I have checked everything. no any errors. :( but it didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to duplicate the module in order to create new tabs.

In app/code/local/Excellence/Pay/etc/system.xml:

The `<pay>` tags and the information inside of them determine the configuration of the 'Excellence Payment Module' tab.

You can create more tabs, but the tag names have to be unique, so you cannot use `<pay>` again.

Try adding this as an example, just underneath the closing `</pay>` tag and see if it works for you:

```
<paye translate="label" module="pay">
    <label>Excellence Payment Module 2</label>
    <sort_order>770</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</paye>
```

Comment: Thks I try to duplicate all code within <pay></pay> and using <paye>. it show more tab on admin :) . however it doesn't show on payment method on checkout page. what should I do next ?